# Weird issue: Bigquery dataset not found

Tags: google-bigquery

One of our BQ datasets is no longer accessible via BQ Web UI and Cloud Shell.

It shows message "Not found: Dataset project:dataset" immediately upon opening the UI.

We tried a couple of bq shell commands as well:

- bq ls: successfully lists the "missing" dataset
- bq ls dataset: returns "BigQuery error in ls operation: Not found: Dataset project:dataset"

But we were able to query the views inside and access the contents of the dataset via PowerBI.

IAM Permission: Owner

Anyone encountering similar issue?

Comment: I am from the GCP support team, I could have a look if you provide the project ID and the dataset. The first place to check is probably the BigQuery logs to see if there is any information related to that "missing" dataset.

Comment: @XiaoxiaLin we have created case 15714078, appreciate if you could look into it. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

I had a similar issue - the BigQuery client library would list the dataset when I called ListDatasets(), but attempting to call UploadCsv() with the same dataset ID would return 404 Dataset not found.

Turns out it was because I had selected 'asia-northeast1' as the Data Location when creating the dataset - it doesn't tell you when you create the dataset that this region is treated differently, but a line in the [BigQuery docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/dataset-locations#specifying_your_location) says:

> If your data is in a location other than the US or EU multi-regional
>   location, you must specify the location when you perform actions such
>   as loading data, querying data, and exporting data.

Re-creating the dataset in the US region fixed my issue. Or you could use the options in the docs above to specify the 'asia-northeast1' location everytime instead.

Comment: My data is in US region, but thanks for the additional info @cometfish.

At that time, there was a caching issue that caused this to happen and was already resolved.

Comment: No worries, glad you got your issue fixed too :) My answer might help others landing here from search like I did

Comment: Weird issue, This fixed it. Thanks :)

Comment: It would be great if BigQuery team can fix the error message to avoid confusion for the users.

Answer (score 0):

At that time, there was a caching issue that caused this to happen and was already resolved.